# Find $^{505}C_5-5\cdot{^{404}C_5}+10\cdot{^{303}C_5}-10\cdot{^{202}C_5}+5\cdot{^{101}C_5}-1$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Find the sum

$$^{505}C_5-5\cdot{^{404}C_5}+10\cdot{^{303}C_5}-10\cdot{^{202}C_5}+5\cdot{^{101}C_5}-1$$

---

Critiques and other answers are always welcome!

Comment: A generalization seems to be $$\sum_{k=0}^n {^{m(n-k)}C_n}{^n C_k}(-1)^k=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{m(n-k)}{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k=m^k.$$ It's not implausible that this has already been considered on this site.

Comment: @Semiclassical: See my answer for a combinatorial explanation for the general case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We have to find the coefficient of $x^5$ in
> $$(1+x)^{505}-5.(1+x)^{404}+10.(1+x)^{303}-10.(1+x)^{202}+5.(1+x)^{101}-1=((1+x)^{101}-1)^5=({101}x+O(x^2))^5$$
> Multinomially expand the final term and convince yourself that the coefficient of $x^5$ is $101^5$

Comment: Nice method using coefficeint extractor that was my same idea too!+1

Comment: WolframAlpha verifies this answer ([link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BBinomial%5B101%285-k%29%2C5%5D%28-1%29%5Ek+Binomial%5B5%2Ck%5D%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C5%7D%5D])).

Answer (score 1):

It is simply the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)... Choosing $1$ from each of $k$ groups of $n$ is equivalent to choosing $k$ from all $k$ groups (combined) minus choosing $k$ from only $(k-1)$ groups plus choosing $k$ from only $(k-2)$ groups ...